# How to style an iframe?

Tags: php, css, iframe

The code for the iframe goes like this since I'm using prettyPhoto

```
<a href="stories/story1txt.php?iframe=true&width=400&height=200" rel="prettyPhoto">
<img src="images/story1.jpg"/></a>
```

and the story1txt.php file looks like this

```
<p>Text goes here...</p>
```

How can I style the php file so the font is Arial Narrow and of 17px? Do I use a link to a css file?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't style the contents of an `iframe` from the page that contains it. You'll need to have the styling information on the "inner/contained" page (in your case, story1txt.php).

---

Edit: In case you're asking for the specific CSS, that would be something like:

```
body {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
}
```